# Correct way of using root.after and root.mainloop in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter interface that needs to be automatically refreshed every 5 minutes. So far there is no problem, you would just have to do something like:

```
root.after(300000, function_to_run, args_of_fun_to_run)
```

The problem is that I have to do this for an "infinite" amount of time. The scenario is that the GUI will running on a PC attached to a TV displaying some info 24/7 in my office. This works for around 8 hours and then I get the following error:

[image]

Now, I know that the traceback goes all the way to a line in one of my custom modules that uses matplotlib. None of my custom modules uses any loops so I knw that the error does not directly come from one of them (please correct me if I'm wrong), so it must be from me repeating the function an infinite amount of time. This is the code from my main function:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import logging
import datetime
import sys

sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\me\Desktop\seprated sla screens')

import sla_main as sla
import main_frame as mf
import sla_grid as sg
import incoming_volume as iv
import outgoing_volume as ov
import read_forecast as fc
import get_headers as hd
import vol_graph as vg
import out_graph as og
import add_graph as ag
import sla_reduction_email as sre

###################################
###################################
###################################
###################################

runs = 0

def maininterface(f_size, pic_x, pic_y):

    global runs
    global root

    start = str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) + ' ' + str(datetime.timedelta(hours=6))

    screen = sla.slamain(start)

    if runs == 0:
        root = mf.mainframe(f_size)

        sg.sla_grid(screen, f_size, root)

        file = open('titles in queue.txt', 'r')

        in_q = file.read()

        file.close

        ttk.Label(root, text=in_q, anchor=CENTER, width=15, font=('times', f_size, 'bold')).grid(column=6, row=2, sticky=E)

    if runs > 0:

        ###################################
        #deletes all rows before making the calculations
        for label in root.grid_slaves():
            if int(label.grid_info()["row"]) > 1:
                label.grid_forget()

        sg.sla_grid(screen, f_size, root)

        file = open('titles in queue.txt', 'r')

        in_q = file.read()

        file.close

        ttk.Label(root, text=in_q, anchor=CENTER, width=15, font=('times', f_size, 'bold')).grid(column=6, row=2, sticky=E)




    ###################################
    #all this part is just info for the graph and the graph

    incoming = iv.incomingvolume(start)

    outgoing = ov.outgoingvolume(start)

    forecast = fc.readforecast()

    headers = hd.getheaders()

    vg.volgraph(forecast, incoming, headers, pic_x, pic_y)

    #og.outgraph(forecast, outgoing, headers, pic_x, pic_y)

    ag.addgraph("vol_graph.png", root, 1)

    #ag.addgraph("out_graph.png", root, 2)

    runs = runs + 1

    globals().update(locals())

    print(str(datetime.datetime.now()))

    root.after(300000, maininterface, f_size, pic_x, pic_y)

    root.mainloop()




logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='error_log.txt')

try:
    maininterface(28, 23.5, 6)

except:
    logging.exception("Oops:")
```

What can I modify here to avoid this error??

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

As many have suggested, I have moved the mainloop call outside of the main function. The las few lines of my code look like this now:

```
try:
    maininterface(28, 23.5, 6)
    root.mainloop()

except:
    logging.exception("Oops:")
```

The root.after call remains inside the function. After running it like this, it closes after 5 minutes. Does anyone know why the mainloop is not being called?

Comment: Call the mainloop outside of the function.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but `file.close` doesn't do anything. You need `file.close()`.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, if that's the answer, please post it as an answer.

Comment: If it's closing after 5 minutes, `mainloop` _is_ running, and something is causing the main window to be destroyed.

Comment: I am getting no exception and I have nothing even similar to root.destroy() anywhere in my code O.o

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### How to use `mainloop` and `after`

In short, the correct way is to make sure you call `mainloop` precisely once, and then have your periodic function reschedule itself when it's done working:

```
root = tk.Tk()
...
def do_one_iteration():
    ... your code here ...
    root.after(300000, do_one_iteration)

root.mainloop()
```

### Remove the recursion

The problem in your code is that you have the call to `mainloop` in the same function that calls `after` -- you're creating an infinite loop during each iteration of your infinite loop. This is the immediate cause of the problem. You need to move the call to `mainloop` out of the `maininterface` function so that it is only called once.

### Fix the memory leak

You also need to refactor `maininterface` a bit. It appears you keep creating new widgets without ever destroying old widgets, which is a memory leak. Eventually your program will run out of memory. Of course, creating just one new widget every five minutes isn't egregious, but it will add up over time for an app that must run 24/7.

It's usually best to simply update existing widgets rather than to destroy and recreate them, but if you are, you need to do more than just call `grid_forget`. All that does is remove them from view, but they are still taking up memory. If you truly want to delete old widgets, call the `destroy` method.

### Close your file properly

You are apparently attempting to close a file with `file.close`, but the proper syntax is `file.close()` (note the trailing parenthesis)

Comment: Ok so your answer makes total sense, I fixed the memory thing and the file closing was a very dumb mistake on my part. However if I move the root.mainloop outside of the function, the GUI closes when I run it (just double click on the .py file) which is why I added it inside the function.

Comment: You have to call `mainloop` _somewhere_. If you don't call it, you'll get the behavior you describe. You must have moved it to a place where it's not getting executed.

Comment: @rodrigocf: are you capturing an exception? Is your code destroying the main window? Either of those will cause the program to exit.

Comment: I am getting no exception and I have nothing even similar to root.destroy() anywhere in my code O.o

Comment: I just found out that root.quit() would "bypass" the mainloop, would adding that at the beginning of my function and keep the mainloop inside the function give me this same error?

Comment: It doesn't "bypass" the mainloop, it simply causes it to exit. For a tkinter program to work, you must create a single instance of `Tk`, and you must call `mainloop` exactly once for the life of that instance. When the window is destroyed, `mainloop` exits.

Answer (score 0):

Call the mainloop outside of the function.