# Plotting higher frequency data using threads in real-time without freezing Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, tkinter, real-time

I'm trying to make an interface that can read EEG signal @ 250Hz (OpenBCI) and display it at the same time. In the future, I'll integrate it with some experiments (like oddball and p300). I have addressed part of my issue in this question a few months back, where I was struggling to set up the thread to acquire data and display the graph: [Reading higher frequency data in thread and plotting graph in real-time with Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62273244/reading-higher-frequency-data-in-thread-and-plotting-graph-in-real-time-with-tki).

But lately, when I tried to make this application get samples until a stop button is pressed I realized it is not working in "real-time". The acquisition part of the thread is working pretty well given the time it is taking to process, but the graphs only show after all my samples are collected (I tested it out with 1500 samples, which take theoretically 6 seconds @ 250Hz and the graphs only start to refresh after roughly 6 seconds), and my interface freezes, not letting me click the button to make it stop.

Does anyone know how to proceed with this case? Should I get my 'plot-graph' function in a thread too (and in case yes, should I treat that `app.root.after`)? And how can I make my interface be still operational while all the signal acquisition happens?

All help is appreciated.
Thanks!

```
##INTERFACE SCRIPT
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import scroller as scrl
import logging
import requests
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg #NavigationToolbar2TkAgg <<Did not work
import random
from pandas import DataFrame
import stream_lsl_eeg as leeg
from FlickeringBoxes import *
import numpy as np

class AppWindow:
    def plotGraph(self, x, y):
        self.ax.clear()
        if isinstance(y, list):
            self.ax.plot(x, y, color = tx_color)
        elif isinstance(y, np.ndarray):
            for i in range(np.size(y,1)):
                self.ax.plot(x, y[:, i], color = tx_color)
        # self.ax.set_xlim([0,249]) def plotGraph(self, x, y):
        self.ax.clear()
        if isinstance(y, list):
            # plot data alternatively
            self.ax.plot(x, y, color = tx_color)
        elif isinstance(y, np.ndarray):
            # print("\n<>Receiveing Array:")
            # print(type(y))
            # print(np.shape(y))
            # print(np.size(y,1))
            for i in range(np.size(y,1)):
                self.ax.plot(x, y[:, i], color = tx_color)
        self.figure.canvas.draw()

    def __init__(self):

#SOME TKINTER ELEMENTS

        ##Application Design
        self.root = tk.Tk() #start of application

        #Button for Getting EEG LSLs inlet
        self.btn_StartEEGLSL = tk.Button(self.EEG_frame, text = "Start EEG LSL Inlet", bg = bg_color, fg = tx_color, state = tk.DISABLED, command = lambda: leeg.getInlet(self))
        self.btn_StartEEGLSL.place(anchor = 'nw', relx = 0.52, rely = 0.15, width = 196, height = 40)
        #Button to test the SSVEP only w/ EEG
        self.btn_txt_Receive = tk.StringVar()
        self.btn_ReceiveEEG = tk.Button(self.EEG_frame, text = "Receive EEG signal", bg = bg_color, fg = tx_color, state = tk.DISABLED, command = lambda: leeg.getEEGstream(self))
        self.btn_txt_Receive.set("Receive EEG signal")
        self.btn_ReceiveEEG.place(anchor = 'nw', relx = 0.52, rely = 0.5, width = 196, height = 40)

#MORE TKINTER ELEMENTS
```

```
#stream_lsl_eeg SCRIPT
from pylsl import StreamInlet, resolve_stream
import tkinter as tk
import AppWindow as app
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import threading
import queue
from queue import Empty
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, q, raw, flag, app = float("NaN")):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.q = q
        self.raw = raw
        self.flag = flag
        self.app = app

    def run(self):
        print("Starting ", self.name)
        pullSamples(self.q, self.raw, self.flag) #place where function is called

#Thread elements
threadLock = threading.Lock()
dataqueue = queue.Queue()
filteredq = queue.Queue()
rawqueue = queue.Queue()
flag = queue.Queue()
flag.put(0)
thread1 = myThread(1,"Thread-1", dataqueue, rawqueue, flag)

#Golbal Variables declaration
rawsamples = []
filtsamples = []
rawtimestamps = np.empty([1,1])
prosamples = []
show_samples, show_timestamps = [],[]
stopcollecting = 0
kounter = 0
chk_chs = [] #this is an array with the channels that will be used


def getInlet(app):
    global inlet
    app.logger.warn('Looking for an EEG strean...')
    streams = resolve_stream('type', 'EEG')
    inlet = StreamInlet(streams[0])
    app.logger.warn('Connected\n--')
    app.btn_ReceiveEEG.config(state = tk.NORMAL)


def pullSamples(q, raw, flag): #THREAD #1
    global stopcollecting
    i = 0
    while i<1500: #<<< in the future: "while flag.get() not 2"?
        flag.put(0) #putting a value at every round because the other function will test it every round
        sample, timestamp = inlet.pull_sample()
        threadLock.acquire()            #thread locks to put info in the queue
        q.put([sample,timestamp])       #data is put in the queue for other threads to access
        raw.put([sample,timestamp])     #raw data
        threadLock.release()            #thread unlocks after info is in
        i += 1
    stopcollecting = 1
    flag.put(1) #thread sends a last flag to indicat it is finished. Once the other thread unpacks the 1, it will know info stream is over


def plotRawSamples(flag, app): #Outside Threads
    global rawsamples
    global rawtimestamps
    rawsamples = np.empty([len(chk_chs),1])
    filtsamples = np.empty([len(chk_chs),1])
    global kounter
    # rawsamples = np.array([[]])
    # rawtimestamps = np.array([])
    while dataqueue.qsize(  ):
        try:
            ss, ts = queue2var(dataqueue, chk_chs)
            if not rawsamples.size == 0:
                rawsamples = np.hstack((rawsamples, ss))
            else:
                rawsamples = np.array(ss)
            if not rawtimestamps.size == 0:
                rawtimestamps = np.append(rawtimestamps, ts)
            else:
                rawtimestamps = np.array(ts)
            if kounter>0 and kounter % 15 == 0:
                if np.size(rawsamples,1)>=250:
                    # app.plotGraph(rawtimestamps[-250:-1], rawsamples[-250:-1,:]) #for lists
                    app.plotGraph(rawtimestamps[-250:-1], rawsamples[:,-250:-1].transpose()) #for numpy
                else:
                    app.plotGraph(rawtimestamps, rawsamples.transpose()) #for lists
            kounter += 1
        except Empty:
            return
    app.root.after(200, plotRawSamples, flag, app)


def queue2var(q, chans):
    ss, t = [], []
    s, t = q.get(0)
    for ch in chans:
        ss.append([s[ch]])
    # t = pd.Timestamp(t, unit ='s')
    ss = np.array(ss)
    ss = ss #.transpose()
    return ss, t


def getEEGstream(app):
    app.logger.warn('|Starting threads...')
    start = time.perf_counter()
    thread1.start()
    ##
    app.logger.warn('|Started...')
    plotRawSamples(flag, app)
    ##
    thread1.join()
## CLOSE THREAD SOMEWHERE HERE?
    finish = time.perf_counter()
    app.logger.warn(f'|Sizes: Samples [{rawsamples.shape}], Timestamp [{rawtimestamps.shape}]')
    app.logger.warn(f'|Sucessfully streamed in {round(finish-start,3)}s!\n--')
    print("\n\n>>>DONE<<<\n\n")
```

Comment: It's really not possible to answer this as is. You will likely need to do some profiling to figure out where the hotspots are. That said, there are some quick efficiency improvements you can make. Plot multiple lines simultaneously, rather than in a loop. Send large chunks of data, rather than single samples, since you seem to be plotting 1-second chunks of data anyway. Use [`draw_idle()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/backend_bases_api.html?highlight=draw_idle#matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureCanvasBase.draw_idle). If all else fails, use a [faster plotting library](http://pyqtgraph.org).

Comment: Thanks for your comment and suggestions @bnaecker. Just to clarify, you are saying it is not possible to answer because the code seems to have the _right logic_? Do you think this might have to do with insufficient hardware capacity?

Comment: Not quite. I mean that you're asking about how to improve performance to achieve a particular result, plotting smoothly on your machine. There are general recommendations, like the ones I've given, but whether or not any of them get you to your goal will depend heavily on the actual machine. Hence you will need to profile to find out what can be improved. Unless you're running this on a tiny/old machine, it should be very possible to plot data of these sample rates. Another suggestion: look into plotting a line _once_, and then just _updating_ it with `line.set_data()`.