# How to avoid Tkinter slowing down as number of shapes increases?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python project with tkinter. On this project I draw small squares over time.
I noticed tkinter is slowing down as the number of square increases.

Here is a simple example that draws 200 red squares on each iteration:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import time

WIDTH = 900
CELL_SIZE = 2
GRID_WIDTH = int(WIDTH / CELL_SIZE)
CELL_PER_ITERATION = 200
SLEEP_MS = 50


root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=WIDTH, bg="black")
canvas.pack()

current_iteration = 0
cell_count = 0
previous_iteration_end = time.time()

text = tk.Label(root, text=f"iteration {current_iteration}")
text.pack()


def draw_cell(x_grid, y_grid):
    x = x_grid * CELL_SIZE
    y = y_grid * CELL_SIZE
    canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + CELL_SIZE, y + CELL_SIZE, fill="red")


def iteration():
    global current_iteration
    global previous_iteration_end
    global cell_count

    current_iteration_start = time.time()

    for _ in range(CELL_PER_ITERATION):
        draw_cell(
            x_grid=random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH),
            y_grid=random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH),
        )
        cell_count += 1

    current_iteration_end = time.time()

    # duration of this iteration
    current_iteration_duration = current_iteration_end - current_iteration_start

    # duration between start of this iteration and end of previous iteration
    between_iteration_duration = current_iteration_start - previous_iteration_end

    current_iteration += 1

    text.config(text=f"iteration {current_iteration} | cell_count: {cell_count} | iter duration: {int(current_iteration_duration*1000)} ms | between iter duration: {int(between_iteration_duration*1000)} ms")

    previous_iteration_end = current_iteration_end


def main_loop():
    iteration()
    root.after(ms=SLEEP_MS, func=main_loop)


root.after(func=main_loop, ms=SLEEP_MS)
root.mainloop()
```

Which gives (time data is written at the bottom of picture):
[image: example0]

And after a few seconds:
[image: example1]

So the time to execute an iteration stays constant. But between two iterations, the duration keeps increasing over time. I don't understand why tkinter is slowing down.

**Is it redrawing the entire canvas (so all already drawn squares) at each iteration ? Is there a way to avoid this slow down ?**

*Note: This is an example, the real project i am working on looks like this: [Slime Mold Simulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGpYMTWFnUE&list=WL&index=5&ab_channel=StuartInkrott)*

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376970/correct-way-of-using-root-after-and-root-mainloop-in-tkinter dont reschedule mainloop reschedule iteration

Comment: It is not square. It is 'y' characters.

Comment: @toyotaSupra no it is not drawing 'y' characters. The `canvas.create_rectangle` is drawing rectangles (and in this case width of rectangles is equal to height of rectangles so it is drawing a square).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding shapes, you are not just colorize pixels. You create graphics with contexts and store them into memory. Instead of abusing the `Canvas` paint a picture and show this picture in the `Canvas` this will be a lot faster and will give you more options to colorize your image that you rather want to draw.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I understand correctly, you advise me to use a library (like PIL for instance) where I can create an image (with a data structure like a matrix), over time I change the values inside the matrix. And at the end of each iteration I replace displayed image by new one. Is that what you advise me to do ?

Comment: @VinceM exactly. You also could use `tkinter.PhotoImage` as well but I belief that `PIL` will be faster or at least easier to handle.

Answer (score 2):

As [@Thingamabobs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13629335/thingamabobs) mentioned, using `tkinter.PhotoImage` would be better:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random
import time

WIDTH = 900
CELL_SIZE = 2
GRID_WIDTH = int(WIDTH / CELL_SIZE)
CELL_PER_ITERATION = 200
SLEEP_MS = 50

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=WIDTH, bg="black")
canvas.pack()

offscreen_buffer = tk.PhotoImage(width=WIDTH, height=WIDTH)
canvas.create_image((WIDTH // 2, WIDTH // 2), image=offscreen_buffer, state="normal")

current_iteration = 0
cell_count = 0
previous_iteration_end = time.time()

text = tk.Label(root, text=f"iteration {current_iteration}")
text.pack()


def draw_cell(x_grid, y_grid):
    x = x_grid * CELL_SIZE
    y = y_grid * CELL_SIZE
    offscreen_buffer.put("red", to=(x, y, x + CELL_SIZE, y + CELL_SIZE))


def iteration():
    global current_iteration
    global previous_iteration_end
    global cell_count

    current_iteration_start = time.time()

    for _ in range(CELL_PER_ITERATION):
        draw_cell(
            x_grid=random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH),
            y_grid=random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH),
        )
        cell_count += 1

    current_iteration_end = time.time()

    # duration of this iteration
    current_iteration_duration = current_iteration_end - current_iteration_start

    # duration between start of this iteration and end of previous iteration
    between_iteration_duration = current_iteration_start - previous_iteration_end

    current_iteration += 1

    text.config(
        text=f"iteration {current_iteration} | cell_count: {cell_count} | iter duration: {int(current_iteration_duration * 1000)} ms | between iter duration: {int(between_iteration_duration * 1000)} ms")

    previous_iteration_end = current_iteration_end


def main_loop():
    iteration()
    root.after(ms=SLEEP_MS, func=main_loop)


root.after(func=main_loop, ms=SLEEP_MS)
root.mainloop()
```

The above have a higher `iter duration` than your implementation, but it is constant, and does not increase much. Same for the `between iter duration`.

To get more insight than manual testing, I made two separate plot using `matplotlib`, for your version and mine:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import psutil

WIDTH = 900
CELL_SIZE = 2
GRID_WIDTH = int(WIDTH / CELL_SIZE)
CELL_PER_ITERATION = 200
SLEEP_MS = 50
DURATION_MINUTES = 1

# Implementation 1 timing data
implementation1_between_iter_time = []
implementation1_iteration_duration = []
implementation1_ram_usage = []

root1 = tk.Tk()
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root1, width=WIDTH, height=WIDTH, bg="black")
canvas1.pack()

current_iteration1 = 0
cell_count1 = 0
previous_iteration_end1 = time.time()
start_time1 = time.time()

text1 = tk.Label(root1, text=f"iteration {current_iteration1}")
text1.pack()

def draw_cell1(x_grid, y_grid):
    x = x_grid * CELL_SIZE
    y = y_grid * CELL_SIZE
    canvas1.create_rectangle(x, y, x + CELL_SIZE, y + CELL_SIZE, fill="red")

def iteration1():
    global current_iteration1
    global previous_iteration_end1
    global cell_count1

    current_iteration_start = time.time()

    for _ in range(CELL_PER_ITERATION):
        draw_cell1(
            x_grid=random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH),
            y_grid=random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH),
        )
        cell_count1 += 1

    current_iteration_end = time.time()

    # duration of this iteration
    current_iteration_duration = current_iteration_end - current_iteration_start

    # duration between start of this iteration and end of previous iteration
    between_iteration_duration = current_iteration_start - previous_iteration_end1

    implementation1_between_iter_time.append(between_iteration_duration)
    implementation1_iteration_duration.append(current_iteration_duration)

    # RAM usage of the process
    ram_usage = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2  # in megabytes
    implementation1_ram_usage.append(ram_usage)

    current_iteration1 += 1

    text1.config(
        text=f"iteration {current_iteration1} | cell_count: {cell_count1} | iter duration: {int(current_iteration_duration*1000)} ms | between iter duration: {int(between_iteration_duration*1000)} ms"
    )

    previous_iteration_end1 = current_iteration_end

    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time1
    if elapsed_time >= DURATION_MINUTES * 60:
        root1.destroy()

def main_loop1():
    iteration1()
    root1.after(ms=SLEEP_MS, func=main_loop1)

root1.after(func=main_loop1, ms=SLEEP_MS)
root1.mainloop()

# Implementation 2 timing data
implementation2_between_iter_time = []
implementation2_iteration_duration = []
implementation2_ram_usage = []

root2 = tk.Tk()
canvas2 = tk.Canvas(root2, width=WIDTH, height=WIDTH, bg="black")
canvas2.pack()

offscreen_buffer2 = tk.PhotoImage(width=WIDTH, height=WIDTH)
canvas2.create_image((WIDTH // 2, WIDTH // 2), image=offscreen_buffer2, state="normal")

current_iteration2 = 0
cell_count2 = 0
previous_iteration_end2 = time.time()
start_time2 = time.time()

text2 = tk.Label(root2, text=f"iteration {current_iteration2}")
text2.pack()

def draw_cell2(x_grid, y_grid):
    x = x_grid * CELL_SIZE
    y = y_grid * CELL_SIZE
    offscreen_buffer2.put("red", to=(x, y, x + CELL_SIZE, y + CELL_SIZE))

def iteration2():
    global current_iteration2
    global previous_iteration_end2
    global cell_count2

    current_iteration_start = time.time()

    for _ in range(CELL_PER_ITERATION):
        draw_cell2(
            x_grid=random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH),
            y_grid=random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH),
        )
        cell_count2 += 1

    current_iteration_end = time.time()

    # duration of this iteration
    current_iteration_duration = current_iteration_end - current_iteration_start

    # duration between start of this iteration and end of previous iteration
    between_iteration_duration = current_iteration_start - previous_iteration_end2

    implementation2_between_iter_time.append(between_iteration_duration)
    implementation2_iteration_duration.append(current_iteration_duration)

    # RAM usage of the process
    ram_usage = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2  # in megabytes
    implementation2_ram_usage.append(ram_usage)

    current_iteration2 += 1

    text2.config(
        text=f"iteration {current_iteration2} | cell_count: {cell_count2} | iter duration: {int(current_iteration_duration*1000)} ms | between iter duration: {int(between_iteration_duration*1000)} ms"
    )

    previous_iteration_end2 = current_iteration_end

    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time2
    if elapsed_time >= DURATION_MINUTES * 60:
        root2.destroy()

def main_loop2():
    iteration2()
    root2.after(ms=SLEEP_MS, func=main_loop2)

root2.after(func=main_loop2, ms=SLEEP_MS)
root2.mainloop()

# Plotting the data
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

# Plotting "Between Iteration Time" for implementation 1
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot([t * 1000 for t in implementation1_between_iter_time], label="Between Iteration - Implementation 1")
plt.plot([t * 1000 for t in implementation1_iteration_duration], label="Iteration Duration - Implementation 1")
plt.xlabel("Iteration")
plt.ylabel("Time (ms)")
plt.title("Timing - Implementation 1")
plt.legend()

# Plotting RAM Usage for implementation 1
ax2 = plt.twinx()
ax2.plot([t for t in implementation1_ram_usage], label="RAM Usage - Implementation 1", color="red")
ax2.set_ylabel("RAM Usage (MB)")
ax2.yaxis.label.set_color("red")
ax2.legend(loc="upper right")

# Plotting "Between Iteration Time" for implementation 2
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot([t * 1000 for t in implementation2_between_iter_time], label="Between Iteration - Implementation 2")
plt.plot([t * 1000 for t in implementation2_iteration_duration], label="Iteration Duration - Implementation 2")
plt.xlabel("Iteration")
plt.ylabel("Time (ms)")
plt.title("Timing - Implementation 2")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")

# Plotting RAM Usage for implementation 2
ax3 = plt.twinx()
ax3.plot([t for t in implementation2_ram_usage], label="RAM Usage - Implementation 2", color="red")
ax3.set_ylabel("RAM Usage (MB)")
ax3.yaxis.label.set_color("red")
ax3.legend(loc="upper right")

# Display the plot
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This has three axis, one for `iter duration` and `between iter duration`, and a third one for ram usage. I set the maximum duration of each implementation to 1 minute.

Here is the image of the dual plot:
[image]

As you can see in the image (and by manual testing), the ram usage is lower as time advance on the second implementation compared to yours. It is slightly lower when starting for the first implementation, however...

The `between iter duration` and `iter duration` are constantly staying at a minimum over time on the second implementation, while the first implementation have it's `between iter duration` and ram usage increasing exponentially over time, and it's `iter duration` staying around 0/1ms at all time.

EDIT: Following the suggestion of [@Thingamabobs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13629335/thingamabobs) in the comment, here is a slightly better version of implementation2:

```py
def iteration2():
    global current_iteration2
    global previous_iteration_end2
    global cell_count2

    current_iteration_start = time.time()

    cells_to_draw = []

    for _ in range(CELL_PER_ITERATION):
        x_grid = random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH)
        y_grid = random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH)
        cells_to_draw.append((x_grid, y_grid))

    for x_grid, y_grid in cells_to_draw:
        draw_cell2(x_grid, y_grid)

    cell_count2 += CELL_PER_ITERATION

    current_iteration_end = time.time()

    # duration of this iteration
    current_iteration_duration = current_iteration_end - current_iteration_start

    # duration between start of this iteration and end of previous iteration
    between_iteration_duration = current_iteration_start - previous_iteration_end2

    implementation2_between_iter_time.append(between_iteration_duration)
    implementation2_iteration_duration.append(current_iteration_duration)

    # RAM usage of the process
    ram_usage = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2  # in megabytes
    implementation2_ram_usage.append(ram_usage)

    current_iteration2 += 1

    text2.config(
        text=f"iteration {current_iteration2} | cell_count: {cell_count2} | iter duration: {int(current_iteration_duration*1000)} ms | between iter duration: {int(between_iteration_duration*1000)} ms"
    )

    previous_iteration_end2 = current_iteration_end

    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time2
    if elapsed_time >= DURATION_MINUTES * 60:
        root2.destroy()
```

And the resulting plot:
[image]
The ram usage seems to be lower or a bit more stable in it's increase.

Comment: Nice piece of work ! :) BTW, You could perform better if you would just use `put` once instead of in each iteration.

Comment: oh, you're right...will try this real quick @Thingamabobs

Comment: Nice job, thank you :) I will use this method on my real project.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much you can do. The canvas has known performance problems when there are tens of thousands of objects on the canvas.